# Flink Kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am using the `KafkaConsumer82` and connector jar version is 0.10.2 and kafka version is 0.9.1 and flink version is 1.0.0.

The Java consumer works fine when I run it from with in an IDE as a standalone main program. But when I run it from `flink run`, then I don't see the messages being consumed and don't see any log in stdout of the JobManager in `1ocalhost:8081`. Please let me know what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step I would suggest getting the versions in sync. If you're using Kafka `0.9` and Flink `1.0.0` I would suggest using `flink-connector-kafka-0.9` version `1.0.0` which contains `FlinkKafkaConsumer09`.

Comment: The issue was with the stdout of flink on localhost:8081 not updating properly.Resolved it by writing the output to a file.